# How to parse JSON from String represention of list of JSONs object?

Tags: java, json, string, list

I have a string of the form

```
String str = "[
             {"id": 1, "name":"Abc", "Eligible": "yes"},
             {"id": 2, "name":"Def", "Eligible": "no"},
             {"id": 3, "name":"Ghi", "Eligible": "yes"},
             {"id": 4, "name":"Jkl", "Eligible": "no"}
             ]";
```

I want to parse each JSON from the list.
Thank you.

Comment: Where's the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero I am still very confused about how to convert this string to list first.

Comment: Unfortunately this is very basic question and asked dozens of times here only. Did you try to research on this?

Comment: Yes, I do but can not find a solution. @PradeepSimha, I am confused because the list is a form of string.

Comment: Then post the code you have tried to above question.

Comment: I have no clue how to convert the string representation of list into the actual list because I can not simply split the from comma because JSON may also contain a comma. @PradeepSimha

Comment: That's what we are saying, if you search stackoverflow or see the duplicate question. You will get clue on this. Once you have clue and idea, that is the best time to ask new question here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233223/discussion-between-utkarsh-and-pradeep-simha).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can provide very crude answer to you question.

Add this dependecy in pom.xml

```xml
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
      ...
    </dependencies>
```

Jave Code:

```java
 public static void main(String... args) {
       String str = "[ {\"id\": 1, \"name\":\"Abc\", \"Eligible\": \"yes\"}, {\"id\": 2, \"name\":\"Def\", \"Eligible\": \"no\"}, {\"id\": 3, \"name\":\"Ghi\", \"Eligible\": \"yes\"}, {\"id\": 4, \"name\":\"Jkl\", \"Eligible\": \"no\"}]";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Object o = gson.fromJson(str, Object.class);
        String name = ((LinkedTreeMap) ((ArrayList) o).get(0)).get("name").toString();
        System.out.println("name is "+ name);
}
```

Output:

```
name is Abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse list from the input json string, there are multiple ways and different libraries you can use to parse.

- Using [json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

Maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20210307</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
 String str = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Abc\",\"Eligible\":\"yes\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Def\",\"Eligible\":\"no\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Ghi\",\"Eligible\":\"yes\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Jkl\",\"Eligible\":\"no\"}]";

     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            int id = ((JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i)).getInt("id");
            String name = ((JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i)).getString("name");
            String eligible = ((JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i)).getString("Eligible");
             
        }
```

---

- Using google [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a class for the object that corresponds to the object in the input list.

In your case it would be:

```java
class Item{
        int id;
        String name;
        String Eligible;
        //getter setter
    }
```

```java
String str = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Abc\",\"Eligible\":\"yes\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Def\",\"Eligible\":\"no\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Ghi\",\"Eligible\":\"yes\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Jkl\",\"Eligible\":\"no\"}]";
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Item>>(){}.getType();
List<Item> items = new Gson().fromJson(str, listType);
for (Item item: items){
   //access the item
}
```